# nginx dynamic forwarding requests coming from users

Tags: nginx, redirect, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a backend application that binds users with server ports (I attribute a random available TCP port to each connected user)

Using NGINX, I want to redirect all requests coming from a user -Identified by his unique `id`- to his actual port (All requests come to port 80 then they'll be forwarded)

The list of ports is stored on a database, I can write those ports to a file of any format easily in my backend.

Comment: **Note:** The backend is developed in `Django`.